# Is representation of an element of a group unique by the generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The 2nd property of 4 properties of a Cayley digraph (Section 7 Generating Sets and Cayley Digraphs Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra) says that there is always one way of joining a dot $g$ to another dot $h$. Well there is a path because $g.w=h$ in a group has a solution for w and it is unique; but how uniqueness implies one path?

**Same** question but in group theory words: can an element $w$ be represented by more than one way of the generators of a group? For example suppose $G$ is generated by ${\{a,b}\}$ and $G$ is non-abelian; is it possible $w=a^{k_1}b^{k_2}a^{k_3}b^{k_4} \dots = a^{k'_1}b^{k'_2}a^{k'_3}b^{k'_4} \dots$ for at least one $k_i \ne k'_i$ ? Otherwise, how to show that $a^{k_1}b^{k_2}a^{k_3}b^{k_4} \dots = a^{k'_1}b^{k'_2}a^{k'_3}b^{k'_4} \dots$ implies $k_i = k'_i$ for all $i$'s?

Comment: There's clearly infinitely many ways to do this in any finite group, because $a^{k+o(a)}=a^k$ (and in any non-free group, for that matter). Better to focus this question on what you really what to know.

Answer (score 3):

There will be uniqueness if and only if $G$ is a free group on those generators, and this is "very rare".

So usually yes, it is possible to have different expressions for the same $w$, take for instance $G= \langle a, b\mid a^2\rangle$. Then $b= ba^2$